# Working with class when all I know is the parent class's name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have two classes: `MyAbstractClass` and `MyExtendClass` written in different files and there are a few functions in `MyAbstractClass`.
What I want to achieve is a directory of all the files that contains classes which extend `MyAbstractClass` and then require them at runtime and working with all of them the same way.
In that case when a new class is written all needs to happened is placing it inside that directory.

I have the filename but how do I work with the class without knowing it's name? All I know is that the class inside the file extends `MyAbstractClass`.
I can do `const inst = require(filename)` but it won't do me much good because the functions are properties inside a field called `MyExtendClass`. I thought of just handling the first field in the `inst` object but it seems to me really ugly and unsafe (Can I be sure it will always be first?).

Edit:
I read a little bit about it and I think that `default export` might help me but I also saw it's considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have that automatically, what you can do simply is to create an `index.js` file in that directory that exports the files contents

Let's imagine a directory like this:

```
Root/
├── classes/
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── classA.js
│   ├── classB.js
└── root.js
```

### ClassA.js

```
export class ClassA { 
    //...
}
```

### ClassB.js

```
export class ClassB extends OtherClass { 
    //...
}
```

Now whatever files you will add you just need to export its exports from index.js like this:

### Index.js

```
export * from './classA'
export * from './classB' 
// ... add here any other file in the directory
// Also you can export a default with a name of your choosing
// export { default as ClassC } from './classC'
```

Now we can import all those classes simply by importing the `index.js` file

### Root.js

```
import * as Classes from './classes'

console.log(Classes) //=> { ClassA, ClassB }
```